# React Native what is type Props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

today I made a new React Native app and noticed something different than the last time I created a native app.

```
type Props = {}
export default class App extends Component<Props> {}
```

What `type Props = {};` is?
I can't really find anything about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code is using [Flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/), and this is how you give the types of the props the component has. This particular component doesn't have any props.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply. Could you please just tell why it couldn't be actually Typescript instead of Flow? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In TypeScript, there are a lot of basic types, such as string, boolean, and number.

Also, in TypeScript, there are advanced types and in these advanced types, there is something called type aliases.

With type aliases, you can create a new name for an existing type, any valid TypeScript type but you can't define a new type.

For example you can use the type alias chars for the string type:

```
type chars = string;
let messsage: chars; // same as string type
```

Or the type alias Props as an object:

```
type Props = {
    src: string
    alt: string 
}   
export default function Image({src, alt}: Props) {   
    return (
        <img alt={alt} src={src}/>
    )   
}
```